# AWS S3 Credentials Provider not found (Java SDK)

Tags: java, maven, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

When trying to build a project on my computer using `mvn test`, the Amazon S3 client is unable to find both the credentials and the region, which are stored in ~/.aws/credentials and ~/.aws/config respectively.

When running the program using mvn exec, the S3 client correctly authenticates and there are no issues with the same function.

**Does anyone know why this is happening?** Would be willing to look into an alternative solution, as I'd like to move the app to a docker container and don't want to have to send credentials to that container anyway.

Full error message:

```
com.airdev.serena.AWSTest  Time elapsed: 10.628 sec  <<< FAILURE!
com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to find a region via the region provider chain. Must provide an explicit region in the builder or setup environment to supply a region.
at com.airdev.serena.AWSTest.before(AWSTest.java:32)
```

Contents of `~/.aws/config`:

```
[default]
region = us-west-1
```

There shouldn't be any permissions issue - the `~/.aws/config` file is readable and I ran the test suite with sudo anyway.

EDIT:

I've tried the following ways of building the S3 Client, and a couple other combinations that I don't have the code for.

`s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.defaultClient();` <- works for maven exec command and when running from Eclipse IDE

```
s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                                     .withRegion("us-west-1") // The first region to try your request against
                                     .withForceGlobalBucketAccessEnabled(true) // If a bucket is in a different region, try again in the correct region
                                     .build();
```

Neither of these seem to be picking up the default credential chain, even when I set environment variables or delete the .aws folder and re-set the credentials through the `aws configure` command.

Comment: How are you creating your S3 client in your Java application?

Comment: @craigcaulfield see the edits above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure default credential provider using aws cli, as you are able to pick with maven exec, this may not be a reason. Use command

```
aws configure
```

To use default credential provider

```
AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                       .withRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_1)
                       .build();
```

You can also provide keys in code explicitly. As you are willing to use docker, credentials need to be inside the docker environment. To use in code

```
BasicAWSCredentials awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials("access_key_id","secret_key_id");
AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                        .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCreds))
                        .build();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Are there security risks to putting these credentials directly in the code? I'd prefer to avoid hard-coding auth keys into the code and keep them in the environment if possible, partly for the flexibility it provides and partly because I'd like to keep the code hosted on GitHub. For the ways I've tried building the S3 Client, see the edited question.

Comment: Tried to test with Regions.US_WEST_1 but no dice.

Comment: Another update - the credentials being used are for an IAM User with full access to all S3 resources on this account. A bucket within the account is the bucket that should be accessed. However, this error occurs: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied. I suppose that maybe there is a bug that is causing it to not access the correct bucket, which only shows up in the test cases? I'll double check this.

Comment: Decided to hard-code the credentials as its working... Thanks for your help!

Comment: There are always risks in hardcoding the credentials in code, if you are deploying On EC2, you can give EC2 role to access S3 and then use default credential provider.